# you are not currently using a display attached to an nvidia gpu

Tags: graphics-card

I bought a Dell n5110 in 2011. I used it to play games. Last week AW also played, but I got a fan problem. (my fan didn't turn on and laptop was shutdown when it overheated) Then I removed the motherboard and I rotated the the fan and removed the bios battery and reassembled.

Then the fan was turned on. I installed win 8.1 and installed the nvidia 340 graphic driver, but when I open the nvidia settings display it says: "you are not currently using a display attached to an nvidia gpu". I tried different drivers-301 ,305, 320, 327, 330 but all have the same problem.

I also tried with win 8 same way, but it has the same problem.(before having those problem I have installed win 8 and i worked with it)

Though I removed the cmos battery the bios didn't reset.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is wrong driver, that laptop "http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/audhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-n5110/drivers" Does not have a nvidia video card chipset, it has a Intel HD Graphics, you can download the correct driver from that link I have provided.

http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-n5110-15-6-core-i3-2330m-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/